# How can session page viewstate be saved and restored in a non-postback, non cross-page postback scenario?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, state, webforms

Currently I restore state by re-querying the database to fill a grid but the page loads too slowly. Instead, I'd like to save viewstate in session variables and restore it as a user re-visits the page. How is this done? Should I use the [SessionPageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx)? This is not a postback situation or even a cross-page postback.

**Background:** I've used the VS 2010 ASP.Net Web Application template with a master page and multiple tabbed content pages. State is lost as you navigate to a new tab. My Customers tab allows the user to filter and select one customer from an AspxGridView. The selected Customer ID is stored in a session variable and used to display related customer data on other tabs: Contacts, Invoices, Tasks etc. I'm able to save and restore the Customer grid filter, sort and layout using [SaveClientLayout](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q201546.aspx). But I don't know how to restore the grid data without re-querying the database.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/DotNetDeveloper/storing-Asp-Net-page-state-on-the-server/) and have implemented the code in the section titled SessionPageStatePersister. I've copied the code and created the SessionPageStateAdapter and the .browser file. I'm confused as to how to access this session viewstate data. I need help with **how to save viewstate and restore it after the user has visited multiple other pages?**

Comment: How slow is your load?  Is there a better solution here to speed up/page your customer grid query?  How many records are you returning?

Comment: Unfortunately the data lives in Vax flat files accessed via a Connx ODBC driver. I'll look into optimization but the Vax and Connx are areas I'm not too familiar with. Optimization may not be as simple as with SQL Server where I could add an index if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Viewstate is a client side way to manage session state.

It injects code inside html rendered page.

So when user close the browser state is not persisted.

If you want to save state across browser session you have two way:

- continue to store it in database.
  If you have performance issues consider using ASP.NET cache
- store your informations in a cookie.

Comment: I'm not attempting to restore state after the browser is closed or across browser sessions. Within the same session I want to restore viewstate after other pages have been visited. The problem as I see it is that viewstate is typically only used for postbacks. Am I trying to do something that is not possible?

Comment: I see. Maybe take a look at [Keeping View State on the Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188774.aspx#S6).

Comment: But I think the best way to handle your scenario "Currently I restore state by re-querying the database to fill a grid but the page loads too slowly. Instead, I'd like to save viewstate in session variables and restore it as a user re-visits the page" is using db+cache or cookies.